# Xamarin - TabbedPage in CarousalPage

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, cross-platform, carousel

We are developing a social media platform. We are using CarousalPage but i need a tabbedpage in home page. When i m trying to do that it gives runtime error and it says carousalpage only takes contentpage. How can i show TabbedPage as a ContentPage or is there an another way to do that?

Comment: Convert to using `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView` as you can embed it in any page

Comment: I'm already using Xamarin.Forms completely

Comment: ?? https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, @Furkan Eraslan wants a TabbedPage to be one of his carousel pages. This does not seem to be a supported scenario.